# Cooperhewitt (or other) font family loading issue in Illustrator running on windows!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, cs6, windows

I have been trying to load the Cooperhewitt font family on Windows 7 running Illustrator CS6.

But it fails to load any font from the family most of the time or sometime only few of the fonts from the family can be seen in the font drop down list. What's wrong?

Even on the font download page it says windows can have only 4 basic weights!
Check on the right column.

http://www.cooperhewitt.org/colophon/cooper-hewitt-the-typeface-by-chester-jenkins/

Is there any way to load all the weights on windows?

Comment: Have you received a warning or error message? Which one? Or have you checked which messagages are found in the system control of windows?

Comment: No error. It's not loading all the fonts as it should. I think fonts have some issue. :(

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use the OTF version and ignore the TTF version. It's Windows TTF which is restricted to 4 faces, but Windows can easily use the OTF version.

The site labeling OTF as a "Mac format" is misleading. OTF is a **universal** format - but then, so is TTF.

Comment: I did that only - but unfortunately it does not list all the fonts in illustrator. Some issues with the fonts I guess. I think they are just Mac snob and didn't bother to configure the fonts properly and making it look like Windows can't load more than 4 styles/weights.

Comment: I doubt that. OTF is OTF and you can't specify what a specific platform sees. You may simply have a conflict with some other font active on your system. With "free" fonts you do get what you pay for more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution for Illustrator that works, from https://github.com/cooperhewitt/cooperhewitt-typeface/issues/4#issuecomment-262857641

> Blockquote
>   Create subfolder with name "Fonts" in the Illustrator Application folder, exemple: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6\Fonts, put in this folder some font files and restart Illustrator. Fonts now are included in the Illustrator font menu.

Comment: Indesign has the same problem, placing the 'problem-fonts' in the Indesign fontmap was the solution!